# SQL override column values with values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, say A and B. Table A associates items with a price:

```
item | price
-------------
book | 20  
copy | 30   
pen  | 10
apple| 5
```

Table B has price corrections for items (including some items possibly not in A):

```
item | price
-------------
copy | 55   
apple| 3
towel| 13
```

Desired output (Table C): select all items from table A. The item's price should be taken from table A, unless a price change is available in table B in which case we take the corrected price:

```
item | updated_price
-------------
book | 20  
copy | 55   
pen  | 10
apple| 3
```

Note: I do not want to change (update) Table A; I only want to query (select) the result (table C)

Answer (score 3):

This is just a simple outer join, using *coalesce* to choose one value if it exists over another

```
select a.item, Coalesce(b.price, a,price) updated_price
from a
left join b on a.item = b.item;
```